# C# How to handle cancel task with eventhandler inside

Tags: c#, .net, task, eventhandler, cancellation

I have requirement to update ui control when status of dependent service will change. I have this sample code, which polling service api to get status and sends result to recalculate and update ui by main thread:

```
public void StartObserving() {
this.cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
this.cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
this.isRunning = true;
var token = this.cts.Token;

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        while (this.isRunning)
        {
            var result = this.serviceAPI.GetStatus();
            this.OnServiceStatusChanged(result);

            await Task.Delay(3000);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        this.isRunning = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.logger.LogError(ex);
    }
}, token);
}
```

And the problem is when I want to cancel above Task. When I call this.cts.Cancel() in another method in this class, I get Exception 'A task was canceled' on dispatcher which was triggered by EventHandler: OnServiceStatusChanged

How I should properly implement this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply check whether the token in cancelled in the inner loop, and exit the loop if it is. No need to pass the token to the Task.Run() method.

```
public void StartObserving()
{
    this.cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = this.cts.Token;

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var result = this.serviceAPI.GetStatus();
                this.OnServiceStatusChanged(result);
                await Task.Delay(3000);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but is not really solve the problem. I guess that when token.cancel is called and application waiting for main thread to update ui, then exception is raised. So it somewhere inside while loop. Maybe some way to handle event handler and cancel when task that own this evenhadler was cancelled?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to simulate this behavior in a console app. Task started, but after calling cts.Cancel(), the task continues to execute... Very strange.

However, I could cancel the task by simply setting this.isRunning to false (instead of calling cts.Cancel()). But I am not sure if this is the solution you want.

Answer (score 0):

If `serviceAPI.GetStatus()` is a blocking call that waits indeffinitly, then you cannot properly cancel this task.

Proper cancellation of `async` methods involves marking safe cancellation points with `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`.

You would have to rewrite `serviceAPI.GetStatus()` as an `async` method that you `await` the result of.  It should contain calls to `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` at points where it can be safely cancelled.  You would want to pass the cancellation token in to *both* that method, and the call to `Task.Delay()` for optimal performance.